# How can I add rules to my android project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following [this tutorial](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5632) and there is one section that says:

> If you use Picasso as your image engine, add rules as Picasso's README says.  And add extra rule:
>
> > -dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.**

am confused on how to add `-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.**`?
I tried `compile '-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.**`  and `compile 'com.bumptech.glide.**` but both attempts failed.

Please can anyone guide me through it?

I am sorry for the beginner question

Comment: Put that line into `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: If you don't know where to put this. Then probably you did not reach that spot where you actually need it. You can ignore this for now. Once you actually plan to release the app on playstore and work on code minification, at that time this will be useful. Ignore it if you are still learning the basics.

Comment: @MohammedAtif Thank you for your advice, appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this rule is related to proguard

so you should add it to `proguard-rules.pro` file

you can read more here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 0):

proguard change the references and the structure (obfuscating names specially ) of your code, for shrinking and security reasons, but that's not good for 3th party libraries.

> Application projects obfuscate the entire code base, including any referenced libraries, so they need proper configuration for the application code and for the library code.
>
> glide in your case

So the rules tell proguard to keep the code as it is (Keep command).

Sample code from gradle

```
minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false

        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
```

so as you see the rules are written in two files, proguard-android is the default file that can be found in your SDK folder.

the proguard-rules is in you app folder.
by `minifyEnabled true` you enable proguard.

so your main issues is you don't know how to add the rules.
Here are ProGuard Rules for most of the famous android libraries [here](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets)
but it always better to check library page, just google it for example glide + proGuard

here is sample code from one of my projects for glide , write it inside **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.GeneratedAppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```